# rotate keyframe goes anticlockwise between 50% and 75%

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with my rotate animation in Internet-Explorer and Edge.

My animation starts normal like in Chrome but after it reached 50% it goes anticlockwise to 75% and then clockwise again to 100%;

I use rotate3d because it use the GPU and not only the CPU.

http://codepen.io/kmathmann/pen/RaGqRr

---

### CSS

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 5s normal linear infinite;
  animation: rotate 5s normal linear infinite;
}


@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 270deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 270deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you need so many keyframes when the splits are equi-distant?

Comment: Yes, without it doesn't works in safari. And in IE it also doesn't work with only 0% and 100% there i need three parts to make it work.

Comment: Note: no errors here with using `rotateZ()` [test](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqKeYz).

Comment: Yes this work but i think it do not use the GPU because the performance is below transform3d. So I can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use 2d transform and add null 3d transform `translateZ(0)` to force GPU usage:

```css
.rotate {
 -webkit-animation: rotate 5s normal linear infinite;
 animation: rotate 5s normal linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)  translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(0);
 }
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(0);
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(0);
 }
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(270deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(270deg) translateZ(0);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(360deg) translateZ(0);
 }
}

@keyframes rotate {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(0);
 }
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(0);
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(0);
 }
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(270deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(270deg) translateZ(0);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(360deg) translateZ(0);
 }
}

div {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: black;
 text-align: center;
}

div > span {
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate" >
  <span>top</span>
</div>
```

[Pen updated](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaKgPV).

Note: this will solve your issue, but it does not answer why IE/Edge does not use clockwise rotation with positive vector.